# UICollection View with text box at the top

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an app written in Swift that has a collection view with a bunch of buttons on it.  In my navigation bar at the top of the page I have a text box for a password (sort of like a search box I see in tutorials).

[image]

When I switch the switch, I get a callback with the item associated with the switch.  I cannot figure out how to access the password text input from the UICollectionViewCell.  Here is what the cell looks like:

```
import UIKit

class GDCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var door: Door!
    @IBOutlet weak var doorSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    // ???HOW TO GET UITextField at the top of the page???

    @IBAction func switchFlipped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Switch flipped for \(door.id), locked is \(doorSwitch!.on)!")
        var uri: String = "\(door.command_uri)\(doorSwitch!.on)"
        print("Request: \(uri)")
        print(self.contentView.classForCoder)

    }

}
```

Here is how I'm setting up the cell in my view controller:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GDCellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GDCell
    cell.door = doors![indexPath.item]
    cell.label.text = "\(doors![indexPath.item].name)"
    cell.doorSwitch.on = doors![indexPath.item].status == "Locked"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. option: delegation**

The cleanest way is probably to create a protocol called something like `GDCellDelegate` which offers one method called `cellSwitchFlipped(sender: GDCell)`. The `GDCell` gets a property of type `GDCellDelegate` called `delegate`.

You then make your viewController conform to that protocol and implement some logic into it.

In your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you assign the cell'S delegate to `self`.

Finally you may have to tell the cell its index and pass that index back using the protocol method to be able to react accordingly in the viewController. That would change the signature of the method to `cellSwitchFlipped(sender: GDCell, index:Int)`.

**2. option: *handing yourself over***

Simply create a new property in the `GDCell` whose type matches the one of the password field. Then assign the value of that property the same way you assign the `door` property in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I am trying to understand option 1.  For option 2, how does that work if the password changes after the cells are rendered?  I am trying to avoid storing the password field on each of the repeated elements, because every time it changes I have to loop through them and update it.

Comment: @mikeb you do not have to do that, the cells know the field, not the text, therefore they can always get the current text from it. Or do the labels have to react to a change of the password field? In that case you should not just loop yourself, but simply call `reloadData`

Comment: Right, I did not get your answer the first time.  That works.

Comment: @mikeb okay, you went for option 2 then!?

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple fix for this.  I added a reference to the UITextField to the View controller:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var doors: [Door]?
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
```

Then, when creating a cell in the ViewController:

```
//3
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GDCellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GDCell
        cell.door = doors![indexPath.item]
        cell.label.text = "\(doors![indexPath.item].name)"
        cell.doorSwitch.on = doors![indexPath.item].status == "Locked"
        cell.passwordTextField = self.passwordTextField
        return cell
    }
```

Finally, reference the UITextField in the cell:

```
class GDCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var door: Door!
    @IBOutlet weak var doorSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func switchFlipped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Switch flipped for \(door.id), locked is \(doorSwitch!.on)!")
        var uri: String = "\(door.command_uri)\(doorSwitch!.on)"
        print("Request: \(uri)")
        print(self.contentView.classForCoder)
        print(self.passwordTextField.text)  
    }

}
```

Works just as needed.